# VSCODE: Paste with indentation relative to first line

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I try to copy/paste in vscode the result is not what i want:

I copy the lines with a, b and c:

```
def func():
    a()
    b()
    c()
```

When i then paste on a line with different indentation, it produces the following result:

```
a()
    b()
    c()
```

but i want this:

```
a()
b()
c()
```

That is, the relative indentation among the copied lines should stay the same.

Is there any way to achieve this? Thanks for any help! :)

Answer (score 1):

Add the following settings to your `settings.json` file:

```
    /** @file "./.vscode/settings.json" */

    {
        "editor.autoIndent": "keep",
        "editor.wrappingIndent": "same"
    }
```

The first one configures regular indenting, and the second one configures, how lines that wrap are indented. I believe the above will give you exactly what you want. Just incase though, you can play with the different configurations.

##### Assignable Values for `"editor.autoIndent"`

---

1. ###### `none`   —   *"Does not auto indent"*
2. ###### `keep`   —   *"Will keep the line's current indentation depth"*
3. ###### `brackets`   —   *"Keeps the current indentation depth, except inside of brackets where autoIndent will add +1 indent level"*
4. ###### `full`   —   *"Language defined rules. Changed the behavior of the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key, on a per language basis, which generally equates to small formatting details that are consistent with most modern standard formatting rules."*
5. ###### `advanced`   —   *"Keeps the current indentation for lines, but uses language defined rules when inside of brackets. Also changes the behavior of the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key, on a per language basis."*

The editor will keep the current line's indentation and honor language defined brackets.

---

##### Assignable Values for `"editor.wrappingIndent"`

---

1. ###### `none`   —   *"Will not indent wrapped lines"*
2. ###### `same`   —   *"Indents wrapped lines at the same indentation as the line that is being wrapped."*
3. ###### `indent`   —   *"Indents wrapped lines +1 more indentation level than the original indentation level as the line that is being wrapped."*
4. ###### `deepIndent`   —   *"Indents wrapped lines +2 more indentation level than the original indentation level as the line that is being wrapped."*

---

For more information about configuring the opensource ***V.S. Code*** editor, or to read specifically about the settings, and customized configurations above, visit the [VSCode Settings Documentation (CLICK HERE)](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_default-settings).

Comment: Thanks for you reply, but unfortunately the problem is still there. I tried all of the possible combinations of the two settings and all lines were still at the same place... :(

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: Oh crap, you know what, try configuring `"editor.detectIndentation"` to have a false value, (i.e. `"editor.detectIndentation": false`) I always keep this off, because once a file is opened with certain indentation, it doesn't matter what you do, because the editor remembers it. Set this to false, then try using the configurations in my answer.

Comment: Hi! Once again, thanks for your help! Even with editor.detectIndentation set to false the problem remains... I'm using python, so I'm assuming that makes it harder since indentation affects behaviour!

Comment: I got it working by binding paste and indent to my cmd+v: [link](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=partkyle.paste-and-indent)

Comment: Yea, the language makes a big difference. Okay well great I am glad you got it working. I am going to delete my answer since it wasn't help. I guess you can answer with what you had to do. To bad you had to bind the indentation to CTRL+V though, seems like there should be something better.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for this behavior since switching from Sublime. [Rubymaniac paste-and-indent extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Rubymaniac.vscode-paste-and-indent) works for me.

Simply install the extension and add a short cut for paste-with-adjusted-indentation to your keybindings, for example:

```json
  {
    "key": "ctrl+shift+v",
    "command": "pasteAndIndent.action"
  }
```